# while loop should exit current loop when error and start new loop

Tags: shell

I am writing script where input will be picked line by line from file in while loop and also it has time condition (should run for 1 or 2 min) where 2nd line goes in error it exist from the complete while loop , where i want only current loop should exit and start with 3 rd line

Code:-

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
 while [[ $i -lt 30000 ]]; do
--log into DB-- 
if grep -v -F 'ERROR' "$checker" ; then
    echo 'Error message, some query has failed' >&2
exit 1  ##  I dont want this to exit whole script but want to come out of current loop 
fi
  echo "Number: $i"
  ((i++))
  tnow=$(date +%M)
  echo $tprev
  echo $tnow
    if ((tnow-tprev>=$TIME_MIN)) ;then
       echo "The script successfully ran for $TIME_MIN minutes, exiting now.."
       break
  fi
done
done < "$input"
```

Please need some advise
Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for `break` to break out of the loop?

Comment: Another option is to put this functionality in a function and `return`

Comment: Thanks for quick response , could you please provide example how can i do this?

Comment: Just replace `exit 1` with `break` or `return`.

Comment: I tried this but then same error statement  runs for next condition ie. for some mins , I want error should skip that line and pick up new input line

Comment: In this case, use `continue` instead of `break`.